# can we toggle between tree view and flat view?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is it possible to provide a feature that allows user to  have both tree view and flat view options for same data in the same grid

For eg

Tree view

I can see data as nested/linked

Parent row

- child row

In flat view: just display child rows

child row

Comment: Are you refering to [master detail](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to flatten the tree, simply return the last item in the tree path. You also need to reset all rows to apply the change.

```js
const displayTree = React.useRef(true);
const updateDisplayTree = (tree) => () => {
  displayTree.current = tree;
  gridApi.setRowData(rowData);
};

...

<button onClick={updateDisplayTree(true)}>Tree</button>
<button onClick={updateDisplayTree(false)}>Flat</button>
<AgGridReact
  treeData
  autoGroupColumnDef={{
    headerName: "Organisation Hierarchy",
    minWidth: 300,
  }}
  getDataPath={(data) => {
    if (displayTree.current) {
      return data.orgHierarchy;
    } else {
      return data.orgHierarchy.slice(-1);
    }
  }}
  {...}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit AgGrid Tree Last Child (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

In `ag-grid-enterprise` version `30.0.2`,you can switch between flat view and tree view by setting `treeData` boolean and providing corresponding `rowData`.

```
const autoGroupColumnDef = useMemo(() => {
 return {
  headerName: "Organisation Hierarchy",
  minWidth: 300,
  cellRendererParams: {
    suppressCount: true
  }
 };
}, []);
const getDataPath = useMemo(() => {
 return (data) => {
   return data.orgHierarchy;
  };
 }, []);

<AgGridReact
          ref={gridRef}
          rowData={rowData}
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
          autoGroupColumnDef={autoGroupColumnDef}
          treeData={treeData}
          animateRows={true}
          groupDefaultExpanded={-1}
          getDataPath={getDataPath}
        />
```

Here is codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-toggle-tree-data-dzvlhx

https://codesandbox.io/embed/ag-grid-toggle-tree-data-dzvlhx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark